# iOS Block Scoping while traversing array

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, objective-c-blocks

I am attempting to traverse an array in order to calculate a value, modeled by the code below:

```
double foo = 0;

[sortedKeys enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
  foo += (NSNumber*)[obj doSomething].doubleValue
}];
```

However I get an error that foo is not scoped appropriately, how can I set foo up so that the block sees it and can modify it when it runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `__block` to the declaration in order to be able to *modify* a variable from inside the block:

```
__block double foo = 0;
```

Comment: Haha, beat me by 10 seconds. +1

Comment: Are there any ARC implications to doing this?

Comment: @Andrew there can be, if you are dealing with multithreading & weak refs, But when using a primitive (e.g. A double) there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: @AndrewLauerBarinov No, in case of a `double` variable there are no ARC implications of this: the compiler simply adds the necessary "magic" to make sure the variable is modifiable from inside the block, and that the block does not end up with a dangling pointer. In your case, the block is used synchronously, so you in particular have nothing to worry about.